# PHP の curl でイントラネットのサーバに接続できない

Tags: php, php-curl

パッケージ版サイボウズガルーンのSOAPAPIを今まで問題なく使っていたのですが、
何かが原因でAPIで取得ができなくなり困っております。

症状としては、curlを使った通信がイントラネット側サーバに到達できないという症状です。

下記コードのaaaaaをホスト名にするとDNSエラーのページが返ってきて、
IPアドレスにしても、タイムアウトになります。
クラウド版も利用しているので、URL自体をクラウド用に変えると正常にxmlが返ってきます。
（URLをhttps://www.google.com/にすると、HTMLの戻りがありますが、イントラサーバーのURLだとDNSエラー）

なお、file_get_contentsを使うとパッケージ版、クラウド版両方まったく問題なくxmlが返ってきます。

サーバはwindows2012でガルーンと同じセグメントに設置してあり、
winhttpプロキシは無しの状態（IEオプションのプロキシはセット）

別のwindows2012サーバに同じバージョンのPHPをセットして、同じコードを試しましたが問題ありませんでした。
サーバーの再インストールしかないのでしょうか…

```
 echo curl_get_contents( "http://aaaaa/scripts/cbgrn/grn.exe?WSDL", "", $timeout = 60 );    
 //echo  file_get_contents("http://aaaaa/scripts/cbgrn/grn.exe?WSDL");
 exit;
    
 function curl_get_contents( $url, $request, $timeout = 60 ){
        $ch = curl_init();
        $header = array('Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8;');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        $result = curl_exec( $ch );
        curl_close( $ch );
        return $result;
 }
```

Comment: まずはエラーをキャッチしてみてはいかがですか？通信できていないのであれば何かしらエラーが発生しているものと推察されます。https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.curl-error.php

Comment: エラーログを吐き出すようにしてみましたが、空白しか記録されません。エラーがないようです…

Answer (score 2):

自己解決しました！

イントラ側向けには明示的にプロキシを空でセットしないといけないようです…

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '');
```

さらにわかりづらいことに、一度この処理を走らせると記憶されるようで
以降このサーバーに関しては上記一文なしでもいけてしまうという('Д')…